# What causes this hanging command prompt in a Django project

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, url-pattern

[image: This]

This hanging prompt on any commands that involve *migrate*, *makemigrations* etc.
I have other Django projects that work fine and I have no idea what is making it do this on this one.

Since I had no data in any of the models/tables I've completely removed the *db.sqlite3* file and all **migrations** files from all the apps involved in the project, and it still hung (as in the image) on the initial `migrate` command even though it recreated *db.sqlite3*. If I run `makemigrations` on any project app it creates *0001_initial.py* and says things are **ok** but when I run `migrate` after it says there's nothing new to migrate. I've been messing with this for hours and I still have to ***ctrl-c*** out of these types of commands before they have completely terminated.

I've even let them sit while I did other stuff and many minutes later I return to a still hanging command prompt.

Pleeeeease tell me this has happened to someone else and/or someone knows how to fix this.

Thanks

EDIT: I've managed to pinpoint what is making it happen, but have no idea why.

one of my project level urlpatterns is causing it

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #path('clink/', include('clink.urls')),
    path('', include('searchnet.urls')),
]
```

When the commented out one (clink) is active it causes *searchnet* migration attempts to hang. There are no models made on *clink*, never done a migration there, and it's only connected to *searchnet.index.html* by a link that goes to an innocuos landing page.

Anyone have any input or thoughts to why this is happening??

Comment: Please show where you are defining this link in your code and your migration files too, if you comment out the searchnet url include does your migration succeed?

Comment: I have same here, after I have added Redis and Channel Layers via Redis (from django-channel). Do you use such something too?

Comment: ... and, most important, I have used threading in AppConfig.ready(). And probably the last one is problem.